# How to setup AWS MediaLive with RTSP input?

Tags: amazon-web-services, camera, rtsp, aws-media-live

I want to set up a pipeline to transmit my stream to other devices using the output link created by CloudFront. The problem is: I couldn't manage to make AWS MediaLive accept the RSTP input.

[image]
https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/live-streaming-on-aws/

Answer (score 1):

Currently AWS does not support RTSP input.

Here are two useful documents that shows list of inputs currently supported on MediaLive and how to create them.

[Supported Inputs on MediaLive.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/medialive/latest/ug/inputs-supported-containers.html)

[How to create MediaLive Inputs.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/medialive/latest/ug/create-input.html)